# Emacs 26.3 cannot call R

Tags: osx, ess, r

After updated to macOS Catalina (10.15) I've been trying to use R in Emacs 26.3. However, Emacs is not fetching R by using `M-x R` (Emacs says `[No match]`).

I already checked the paths for both R and Emacs in the Terminal, both are in `/usr/local/bin`. Also, I checked `M-x getenv PATH` within Emacs. This is the result:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_14:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-x86_64-10_14
```

Can anyone help me with this please? Any ideas to fix the problem? Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Apparently there is no Emacs command named `R` in your setup.

Comment: Have you (re-)installed ess? You need that to run R.

Comment: The command `R` disappeared somewhere between version 16 and 18 of `ESS`. See [#787](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/787) of the `ESS` git repository on github. Solutions are discussed there. You can define your own alias but you must wait for the detection of the newest `R` version. The problem should be solved in the newest version of ESS directly from github since the ticket is closed with a commit. `R-newest` should be some replacement for `R` (see the [comment of jabraham](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/787#issuecomment-446004965)).

Comment: @Tobias the problem you link to was fixed in April; the version of ESS in Melpa includes the fix. So just reinstalling ESS from Melpa should fix the problem.

Comment: @Tyler - Thank you very much for your help. I re-installed `ESS` and R came back in Emacs. @Drew and @Tobias, thanks for your comments and for editing my question, I appreciate you!

Comment: @Tyler Please convert [your comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53234/emacs-26-3-cannot-call-r#comment83065_53234) into an answer to mark this question as done.

Answer (score 2):

The command `M-x R` is provided by the package [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/), which is available via the Melpa repository. You need to install this package before you can start the R process this way.

There was a period in early 2019 when the `R` command was broken in ESS, but it has since been fixed, so installing the current release of ESS should restore the `R` command.

Comment: Confirming this works on Big Sur after installing macOS R app from official source.